# Declare a multimap with four values for a key

Tags: c++, multimap

What syntax should I use to declare a multimap with four values for a key?

I would like to add two more values from the type *unsigned int* after the sc_core sc_time values.

```
      std::multimap<std::string, std::pair<sc_core::sc_time, sc_core::sc_time> >
```

Thanks

Comment: Just create a template that's exactly like a pair except it's a quad.  More awkwardly you can use a struct or a pair of pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a tuple for that:

```
std::tuple<key_type1, key_type2, key_typ3, key_typ4>
```

For example:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::map<std::tuple<int, int, float, float>, std::string> myMap;  // if you meant 4 values as a key
    std::map<std::string, std::tuple<int, int, float, float>> myMap2; // if you meant 4 values for each string key

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I would like to note that when declaring a map, the template argument for the key goes first and then the value type (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)). Your post was ambiguously formulated so I didn't know if the four values were supposed to be the key or the value so I showed both possibilities.

EDIT: As Jamin Grey nicely pointed out you can shorten this unfathomably long type using a typedef:

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int, float, float> MyKeyType;
```

Once you've done this you can use `MyKeyType` in your code instead.

Comment: +1 @wschcom: Typedefs help in this situation, if you use it. **typedef std::tuple<int,int,float,float> MyReasonablyNamedType;**

Comment: Though, the OP may mean, "*I want four values for one key*", not necessarily, "*I want four values **as** one key*". Same deal though, just swap their locations. I read it the same way as first, and was confused at what the OP meant. =)